# Why are the Lonely Mountain and the dwarfs not shown in Lord of the Rings?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, movie, the-hobbit

This has really been bugging me after watching the three Hobbit films and then, even though I had already watched them thousands of times, the Lord of the Rings trilogy (only to get a real insight into what actually happened to Middle Earth as such).

When I watched the Lord of the Rings again, they don't really mention anything about the Lonely Mountain, or about the dwarves and why they didn't help in the battle in Return of the King. They only really spoke about Moria and Balin being killed.

Someone please put my mind at rest and explain why this is.

Comment: It's been a while since I last read it but I'm pretty sure Gimli was the son of Gloin and came to Rivendell from the reestablished Dwarf Kingdom of Erebor. I'm also slightly less but still reasonably certain that Gloin was at the council of Elrond that established the Fellowship of the Ring.

Comment: “to get a real insight of what actually happened to middle earth” — you are aware that the places and events in Lord of the Rings aren’t real, yes?

Comment: Why is a question about dwarves marked as a duplicate of a question about elves?

Comment: @Dronz Because the answer on that other question answers this question.

Comment: @Keen Ok so if an answer to a different question accidentally answers another question, the other question becomes a duplicate question? Hmm.

Answer (score 9):

The Dwarves and Men of Dale did not assist Gondor because, like most other kingdoms in Middle Earth, they were facing danger and battles of their own.

> At the same time as the great armies besieged Minas Tirith a host of the allies of Sauron that had long threatened the borders of King Brand crossed the River Carnen, and Brand was driven back to Dale. There he had the aid of the Dwarves of Erebor; and there was a great battle at the Mountain's feet. It lasted three days, but in the end both King Brand and King Dáin Ironfoot were slain, and the Easterlings had the victory. But they could not take the Gate, and many, both Dwarves and Men, took refuge in Erebor, and there withstood a siege.
>
> When news came of the great victories in the South, then Sauron's northern army was filled with dismay; and the besieged came forth and routed them, and the remnant fled into the East and troubled Dale no more. Then Bard II, Brand's son, became King in Dale, and Thorin III Stonehelm, Dáin's son, became King under the Mountain. They sent their ambassadors to the crowning of King Elessar; and their realms remained ever after, as long as they lasted, in friendship with Gondor; and they were under the crown and protection of the King of the West.

From the Lord of the Rings appendices.

This attack was foreseen:

> We discover that messengers have come also to King Brand in Dale, and that he is afraid. We fear that he may yield. Already war is gathering on his eastern borders. If we make no answer, the Enemy may move Men of his rule to assail King Brand, and Dáin also ’

(Gloin, in Council of Elrond)

Aside from that, they are not mentioned because Dale and Erebor are not on the way to Mordor and are uninvolved in the Quest. In the book, Sauron does also send emissaries to Erebor to seek for Bilbo and the Ring.

> ‘Then about a year ago a messenger came to Dáin, but not from Moria - from Mordor: a horseman in the night, who called Dáin to his gate. The Lord Sauron the Great, so he said, wished for our friendship. Rings he would give for it, such as he gave of old. And he asked urgently concerning hobbits, of what kind they were, and where they dwelt. “For Sauron knows,” said he, “that one of these was known to you on a time.”

Comment: That last quote especially is great, what's the source for it?

Answer (score 2):

The Lonely Mountain and the dwarfs are mentioned on the Lord of the Rings book but not shown in the movie.

Peter Jackson has altered the story quite a bit, but also the movies couldn't be 10 hours long each; he had to cut some stuff out. The Lonely Mountain is one of them.

It is mentioned that the Kingdom under the Mountain was restored with King Bard's help and the land prospered.

Some of the dwarfs,lead by [Balin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Balin_(Middle-earth)) preferred to leave Erebor and go and live in Moria (but where killed by the orcs, as we see in the movies).